# Ionic ngCordova Google Analytics & AdMob

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic-framework, ngcordova

So I am using ngCordova for most of my apps and I have recently had to chose between having admob or google analytics included because of a conflict in the plugin. [Google analytics](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/googleAnalytics/) on its own works and [Admob](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/adMob/) works on its own. However when you combine them you get a gradle error because they both require google play services. I have tried using Admob, Admob-Pro and GA and installing them in various orders and nothing works. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: See FAQ 3 in wiki: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/Difference-of-Plugin-IDs

Comment: as Raymond said in the above comment the npm implementation of cordova but i found a tutorial for ionic implementation of admob it does not use the ngCordova extension set but it works http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-banner-ads-to-ionic-apps-using-admob-pro-plugin/